# Javascript Promise.all() executes before function is done, node.js request library

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use node js request, to make a requests to an other site, so request is asyncronis function, I need to execute a code after its all done, but for some reason Promise.all() executes before, here is the code:

```
          // in this object I store request's promises
         var tempObj = {};
         for (var i = self.numberOfPaginations.length; i >= 1; i--) {

            tempObj['request'+ i] = request('http://www.somewebsite.com/search/page='+i ,function (err,resp,body) {
             // gets urls of listings
             if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {

                    var $ = cheerio.load(body);

                     $('.title').each(function() {
                        self.urls.push($(this).attr('href'));
                     });

                     $('.info a').each(function () {
                         self.urls.push($(this).attr('href'));
                     });

                     // this log out puts the desired result
                     console.log(self.urls);

             }



            });



         }  
            // this line of code pushes promises into array
            Promise.all(Object.keys(tempObj).map(function (key) {return tempObj[key]})).then(function (argument) {
                // this line of code executes before all the work in requests is done , however it should not!
                console.log(self.urls);

            });
```

so my problem is that the line of code in Promise.all() executes before, for some reason,

Comment: `request()` doesn't return a promise.

Comment: ops, than should I create a promise? I don't have mush experience in promises

Comment: then read some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and see how you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either use [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) or sort of promisify the request function with something like this:

```
requestAsync = Promise.promisify(request);
```

(However I never tried the second. I used Request-Promise packege to make a web scraper and it works so good).